# With this CSS, how to add iscroll4 in iPad2?

Tags: css, ipad, iscroll4

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/drag.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var myScroll;
      function loaded() {
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
      }
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; ">
  <div id="scroll" style="-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0ms; -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" >
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="myScrollbarV" style="pointer-events: none; -webkit-transition: opacity 0ms 0ms; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; ">
  <div style="pointer-events: none; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0ms cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1); height: 40px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 221px, 0px); ">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is my HTML code for iscroll4 and I am using the following CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 45px;
  bottom: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #AAA;
  overflow: auto;
}
.scroll{
  position: relative;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.div2{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.myScrollbarV {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  width:8px;bottom:7px;top:2px;right:1px
}
.myScrollbarV > div {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  /* The following is probably what you want to customize */
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#f00), to(#900));
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f00, #900);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f00, #900);
  border:1px solid #900;
  -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip:padding-box;
  -o-background-clip:padding-box;
  background-clip:padding-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -o-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -o-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -o-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

I am just able to view that red scroll but not able to scroll it. Can someone please help me out? Is there any problem in the CSS part of iscroll? I am using [this](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/custom-scrollbar/) as a reference to implement my scroll.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you don't need to declare `var myScroll;` and in fact, you shouldn't. You should be binding the iScroll to the window object so you can deallocate it if necessary, and so you can examine/debug its behaviour.

Set a javascript breakpoint in your browser (the Break on Next button should work) and examine your window.myScroll object. Sometimes, iScroll thinks the calculated height of its scroller or wrapper is zero unless it's manually set, and so it disables vScroll and hScroll by itself.

Try manually executing `window.myScroll.refresh();` in the javascript console after tweaking CSS and it should eventually start scrolling. Then make the CSS changes you did in-browser in the drag.css file.

(PS: you can also remove the inline styles from the scroller and wrapper if you like, as iScroll applies those automatically)